# path.join go up two directories

Tags: go, path, config

I have my main.go file in path `project/cmd/project/main.go` and I have configs for my project stored in `project/config`. I am trying to access my config files from main.go file, but I have problem creating config file path. I have tried `path.join("..", "..", projectDir, "config")` but it didn't work.

Comment: Looks like it should be `../../config`.

Comment: Didn't work in what way? What error or other unexpected output did you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `path.join(projectDir, "..", "..", "config")`. First is base path.

Here is my test code:

```
func TestPath(t *testing.T) {
    path, _ := os.Getwd()
    t.Log(path)
    newPath := path2.Join(path, "..", "..", "config")
    t.Log(newPath)
}
```

And the output:

```
$ go test ./... -run TestPath -v -count=1                                                                                        01:04:45
=== RUN   TestPath
    TestPath: main_test.go:12: /home/fahim/Projects/Golang/go-validator
    TestPath: main_test.go:14: /home/fahim/Projects/config
--- PASS: TestPath (0.00s)
PASS
ok      go-validator    0.006s
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my issue... How could I be so dumb...

Comment: Everyone makes a mistake, no worry